# Can I use indexOf to pull characters from a string

Tags: java

I am trying to use index of to basically print the first letter in a string after each whitespace

I want it to grab the first letter of a persons full name entered to pring back out the intials so if they enterd Billy Bob Joe it would grab BBJ and print it like that I am trying to get it to go from each whitespace +1 to grab the chars.

I cannot use chartAt as I do not know the input the user will give.

I have this code I can get it to go to a certain white space but cannot get it to grab just the first letter after the whitespace it take the whole strign after it

```
        String str ="Billy Joe Bob";

    int targetMatch = 1;
    int offset = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < targetMatch; i++){
         int position = str.indexOf(' ',offset);
         if(position != -1){
              offset = position+1;            
            }
         }

    String result = str.substring(offset);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you split the string?  I would solve this by calling String.split(' ') and running charAt(0) on each element (after checking the length of course).

Comment: Why can't you use `charAt`? what problem could occur? Are you worried about them entering an integer?

Comment: I am 8 weeks into my first semester of a degree for computer science it ofr part of a project for java I was asked to do the lecturer decided it is time we stop using chaAt and started using indexOf instead, that is the only reason if I could have used charAt it would have been so much easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str ="Billy Joe Bob";

    int targetMatch = 1;
    int offset = 0;
    int position = str.indexOf(' ',offset);
    String result = "";
    result += str.substring(0, 1);
    while(position != -1){
        position++;
        result += str.substring(position,position+1);
        position = str.indexOf(' ', position);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Try this

Comment: Good stuff. You even followed the rules. +1.

Comment: Thank you I believe I can make this work for what I need :) also thank you Mike your inital answer was very helpfull as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd just split the string on whitespace using `String.split`. E.g.

```
String str = "foo bar qux";
for(String tok: str.split("\s+"))
     System.out.println(tok.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of is to use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String str ="Billy Joe Bob";
for (String word : str.split("\s+")) {
    if (word.length >= 1) {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(0));
    }
}
```